# Making a button unclickable after clicked once

Tags: javascript, php

I have got a code segment that i need to modify so that the button can only be clicked once.

I've tried various methods and not managed to succeed so far. I believe i need to use javascript,  but it's really not my strong point and i'm a bit lost.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Code snippet is:

```
$the_button = '<input type="hidden" name="cart_quantity" value="1"/>' . zen_draw_hidden_field('products_id', (int)$_GET['products_id']) . zen_image_submit('add_to_cart3.jpg', BUTTON_IN_CART_ALT) . '<span id="button_cart" style="padding-left:6px;"></span>';
```

Comment: First of you need to show the code where the button is. In my previous answer (that i deleted) I've put the code for a input type button or submit. Did note that it was an inpyt hidden type. So show us where is your button on your code. And if you have an Submit button the @KLVTZ answer should work, but you will need to include the jquery on your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pepper it with some JavaScript like this:

```
$params = 'onclick="var me=this;setTimeout(function(){me.disabled=true;},1);"';
zen_image_submit('add_to_cart3.jpg', BUTTON_IN_CART_ALT, $params);
```

The third parameter of `zen_image_submit()` allows for extra tag parameters to be added.

Alternatively, you can use the fourth function argument to add a class:

```
zen_image_submit('add_to_cart3.jpg', BUTTON_IN_CART_ALT, '', 'disable-after-click');
```

Afterwards, you define a click handler based on its class name, e.g.:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('disable-after-click'),
clickHandler = function() {
    var me = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        me.disabled = true;
    }, 1);
};

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    buttons[i].onclick = clickHandler;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do the above with jQuery.

Comment: Tried this one: zen_image_submit('add_to_cart3.jpg', BUTTON_IN_CART_ALT, 'onclick="this.disabled=true;"');
but the button wasn't clickable at all. I'll try your second solution

Comment: @StevePrice Oh, right ... my bad :) you should use a `setTimeout()` :)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks Jack.
$params = 'onclick="var me=this;setTimeout(function(){me.disabled=true;},1);"';
zen_image_submit('add_to_cart3.jpg', BUTTON_IN_CART_ALT, $params);

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply JavaScript as a rule to the page that your button is rendered on.
Specifically, you need to add an attribute of disabled upon click while preventing of the default to a click event:

```
$(function(){
  var button = $("input[type=submit]");
  button.on('click', function(e){
        button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        e.preventDefault();
     });
})
```

I've demonstrated a quick way to implement this via [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/aDeDaTIZ/1/) using jQuery.

Comment: That's not JavaScript.

Comment: I've indicated that by implementation via jQuery. If you prefer, I will add in a pure Javascript implementation as well. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @Jack That's is javascript but using JQuery. People nowadays don't learn pure and simple javascript anymore, there are the ones that think that JQuery and Javascript are two different things.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Well, they are two different things and should be learned separately, JavaScript being the first one; it's like not knowing the knife but trying to run a kitchen - there will be blood ;-)

Comment: @JorgeCampos I agree. Learning JavaScript is essential. Many libraries are written and implemented through pure JS -such as node.js. Learning JavaScript will add in constructive foundation into learning a library such as jQuery or Zepto. I treat both, JS and jQuery, with essential precedence and choice when it comes to implementation.

Comment: @KLVTZ Yeah, nowadays as JQuery is one of the most popular framework, everyone should, at least, read about it. Soon or late they will find some code using it. And it is a great point of view of yours.